# How to call a typescript function inside callback of a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback, angular5

I'm using **javascript Google Maps** component in Angular 5 frontend framework

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeGMap()
  }

  initializeGMap() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12,77);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM,
        center: myLatlng,
        scrollwheel: true,
        styles: MAP_STYLE
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    this.initOnMapClickListener();
  }

  initOnMapClickListener() {
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {

      var selectedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
      this.addMarker(selectedLocation)
    });
  }

addMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: this.map,
      icon: './assets/map_marker.png'
    });
  }

}
```

Above is my typescript file, it has three functions

1. initializeGMap() //to initialize google maps
2. initOnMapClickListener() //to initialize on map click listener
3. addMarker(latlng) // to add the marker when onmapclick event happens

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMarker' of null

this is what the console error I'm getting if I run Angular application

Please help to understand how to call a typescript function inside a Javascript callback

Comment: Can you show your html page ?

Comment: <div id="map" class="map"></div>

Comment: Pradeep Join's answer was correct, it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling function using arrow function `=>` like this to bind to the laxical scope of `this` -

```
initOnMapClickListener() {
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => {

      var selectedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
      this.addMarker(selectedLocation)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Perfect solution! (regarding the downvoters, yes please justify yourself!)

Comment: Didn't downvote, but with complex scenarios this way you end up with functions that have hundreds if not thousands of lines of muddled code which are practically illegible.